# How to mutate a complex variable involving dates?

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have a tibble in which each row represents an image of an eye and contains the following relevant variables: `patientId`, `laterality` (left or right), `date`, `imageId`.

I would like to manipulate this to create another tibble showing the number of `followUpYears` for each eye (patientId, laterality). `followUpYears` is defined in a somewhat unusual way:

1. In order to meet the requirements for follow-up in a particular year, there must be two different imaging dates during that year i.e. between days 0-365 for year 1, days 366-730 for year 2 etc. The first image date is always the baseline and `followUpYears` is always an integer.
2. Only one image per date is considered.
3. Follow-up ceases as soon as the requirement for 2 imaging dates in a year is not met i.e. if there is only 1 imaging date in the first year, `followUpYears` is 0 regardless of how many images are taken subsequently.
4. There is no requirement for there to be at least n years between the first and last image date for an eye to have n `followUpYears`.

The following dummy data demonstrates these points:

```
data <- tibble(patientId = c('A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B'),
               laterality = c('L','L','L','L','L','L','R','R','R','R','L','L','L'),
               date = as.Date(c('2000-05-05','2000-05-05','2001-05-06','2001-05-07','2002-05-06','2002-05-07','2000-09-08','2001-09-07','2001-09-09','2001-09-10','2000-09-08','2001-09-07','2001-09-10')),
               imageId = 1:13)

expected_output <- tibble(patientId = c('A','B','B'),
                 laterality = c('L','R','L'),
                 followUpYears = c(0, 2, 1))
```

Patient A's left eye has 0 `followUpYears` because of points 2 and 3. Patient B's right eye has 2 `followUpYears` because of point 4 (despite the fact that there is only slightly more than 1 year between the first and last image date). Patient B's left eye only has 1 year of follow up since it doesn't meet the requirement for 2 image dates in year 2.

I am familiar with the basic dplyr verbs but I can't think of how to frame this type of variable. Note that patients might have one or both eyes included and some might have 10+ years of follow up. Finally, a solution that considers 1 year to be 365 days regardless of leap years is fine.

Thank you!

Comment: Can you add the expected output in your mock data set ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way with `ifelse`. `diff_year` is a helper function that computes the difference between two dates in year rounded to the value above.

```r
library(dplyr)
diff_year <- function(date1, date2) ceiling(as.numeric(difftime(date1, date2)) / 365)
data %>% 
  group_by(patientId) %>% 
  summarise(followUpYears = ifelse(diff_year(date[date != first(date)][1], first(date)) <= 1,
                                   diff_year(max(date), min(date)), 0))

#A tibble: 2 × 2
#  patientId followUpYears
#  <chr>             <dbl>
#1 A                     0
#2 B                     2
```

---

Update with OP's comment. This should work with all conditions:

```r
diff_year <- function(date1, date2) as.numeric((date1 - date2) / 365)
data %>%
  distinct(patientId, laterality, date, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  group_by(patientId, laterality) %>% 
  mutate(diffYear = floor(diff_year(date, min(date)))) %>%
  add_count(count = diffYear) %>% 
  filter(!cumany(lag(n == 1, default = 0)) | row_number() == 1) %>% 
  summarise(followUpYears = ifelse(any(n > 1), ceiling(diff_year(max(date[n != 1]), min(date))), 0))


#  patientId laterality followUpYears
#1 A         L                      0
#2 B         L                      1
#3 B         R                      2
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't believe this solution includes requirement 1 (the need for 2 image dates in each year to be considered as having follow-up). I have added an additional example of Patient B's left eye above to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my approach which should cover all four conditions, I'm not sure however, how you get:

```r
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   patientId laterality followUpYears
#>   <chr>     <chr>              <dbl>
#> 1 B         L                      1
```

since according to your logic it should fall into the two year band from `2000-09-08` to `2001-09-10` are 367 days which equals two years.

The idea is that we first calculate a `followup_flag` which checks if the date is within 365 days of the former date, and then takes the `cummin()` so that the series breaks as soon there is no direct follow up year.

Then we can filter all rows which meet the `followup_flag == 1`.

And for this data set we check how many years are between the first and the last date, and since we want to count 367 as 2 years we have to take the `ceiling()`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

data %>% 
  group_by(patientId, laterality) %>% 
  mutate(followup_flag = cummin(date - dplyr::lag(date, default = first(date)) <= 365)) %>% 
  filter(followup_flag == 1) %>% 
  summarise(followUpYears = as.numeric(
              difftime(last(date), first(date), units = "days") / 365) %>%
              ceiling()
            )

#> `summarise()` has grouped output by 'patientId'. You can override using the
#> `.groups` argument.
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#> # Groups:   patientId [2]
#>   patientId laterality followUpYears
#>   <chr>     <chr>              <dbl>
#> 1 A         L                      0
#> 2 B         L                      2
#> 3 B         R                      2
```

Data used:

```r
data <- tibble(patientId = c('A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B'),
               laterality = c('L','L','L','L','L','L','R','R','R','R','L','L','L'),
               date = as.Date(c('2000-05-05','2000-05-05','2001-05-06','2001-05-07','2002-05-06','2002-05-07','2000-09-08','2001-09-07','2001-09-09','2001-09-10','2000-09-08','2001-09-07','2001-09-10')),
               imageId = 1:13)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. The reason that Patient B's left eye is only 1 `followUpYear` is because **two images on different dates** are required during Year 2 in order to qualify as follow up (condition 1).